# Empty Project in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm taking an online Unity3D class and after some straight C# stuff we're finally diving into Unity proper. When the teacher makes a project it starts with nothing but a Main Camera object. However, when I try to make a new project it comes with a directional light in the hierarchy window and some un-deleteable folders in the project window. Is there a way I can simply start the project as empty?

Comment: Are you sure that the unity version your teacher is using and the one you downloaded is the same?

Comment: What version are you using? Folders in the project window sounds like some kind of plugin or default assets. Undeletable sounds weird though. I think the 3D preset starts with directional light and the 2D starts with nothing but a camera, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: As Fredrik said depending on the kind of project you started will change what your default scenes start with.  The extra files/folders can also be an effect of how you are creating your project such as using the lightweight render pipeline or not.

Answer (score 3):

## Your unity version is different (and that's ok)

Those undeletable folders are there because they are required by Unity in order to function correctly. And they actually exist in your teacher's Unity project too! You just don't see them because the root directory on your version of Unity is in a different place (previously the /Packages directory was hidden because the project window's root director was /Assets, if you were to open both projects in the file explorer window you would find them essentially the same).

The main camera and directional light are just helpful defaults, if you don't need them you can delete them (but most projects do need them).